# How to memoize a recursive function in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm using Matlab R2018a.  This has a "memoize" function, which works at top level, but I don't see how to use it for recursive functions.
For example, I tried this:

```
function z = recfib(n)
  if n == 1
      z = 1;
  else
      z = memfib(n-1)+memfib(n-2);
  end
  fprintf('computed f(%d)=%d',n,z);
end
```

and then

```
memfib = memoize(@recfib);
```

But this doesn't work, as calls to memfib or recfib produce an error:

Undefined function or variable 'memfib'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to stick that `memfib` somewhere that the calls inside the function can see it. If you just do `memfib = memoize(@recfib)` at the command line or in calling code, you end up with a `memfib` variable in the base/caller workspace, not a globally-visible `memfib` function.

I think you can do this with a persistent variable inside the `recfib` function. This works for me in R2019b.

```
function z = recfib(n)
  persistent memfib
  if isempty(memfib)
    memfib = memoize(@recfib);
  end

  if n <= 1
      z = 1;
  else
      z = memfib(n-1)+memfib(n-2);
  end
  fprintf('computed f(%d)=%d\n',n,z);
end
```

Running it twice shows the memoization happening:

```
>> recfib(8)
computed f(1)=1
computed f(0)=1
computed f(2)=2
computed f(3)=3
computed f(4)=5
computed f(5)=8
computed f(6)=13
computed f(7)=21
computed f(8)=34
ans =
    34
>> recfib(8)
computed f(8)=34
ans =
    34
>>
```

(Also, you've got a bug in the base case test; it needs to be `n <= 1`, not `n == 1`, to catch the 0 and -1 cases, because that `memfib(n-2)` line ends up calling `memfib(0)` when n = 2.)